# VScode HTML tag without closing mark

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I use vscode editor. Vscode has emmet, my question is:

How to change emmet or other extension to add / in tags like this `<br/>, <img/>`.

Already I have auto close tag but it is working only for `<div></div>` and other tags.

Comment: Why? It is actively harmful in HTML 4 and earlier. In HTML 5 it is optional, so it is just bloat.

Comment: @Quentin Disagreed. It can be useful if you want to apply basic xml-conformity checks like testing if the document is well-formed. I know many consider this an edge case not worth taking into account, but my opinion on it is that HTML 5 explicitly allows self-closing void elements, and it is very little overhead for what you get, even if the parser *per spec* is required to ignore that closing slash.

Comment: Better to use an actual HTML 5 validator in those cases.

Comment: The other reason is that some template engines like e.g. Thymeleaf won't allow to create non-xml-conform HTML. That is true also e.g. for boolean attributes (not attributes without values).

Comment: I have brackets pair colorizer to html and when tags like <img>, <br> don't have "/" it is not working correctly. Easiest solution right now is to disable this extension to html or you have other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this into your settings:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
   "html": "xhtml"
},
```

Now you will get `<br />` and `<img…..  />`. See [emmet: closing tags xhtml-style](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/#syntaxprofilesjson).

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept the answer if you found it helpful and accurate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have the backslash in empty elements or customize other aspects of Emmet's abbreviations, in your `settings.json` you can do:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "attr_quotes": "single",
        "self_closing_tag": true
    }
}
```

Where `self_closing_tag` corresponds to if an empty element should be outputted with a closing dash.

[Emmet's documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/#create-your-own-profile) has a list of some keys to creating your own output profile